# Is the Holy Watcher of Daniel 4:23 of a Similar Class to those Found in Scroll of Enoch?

Tags: prophecy, angels, daniel

Daniel makes mention of a holy watcher, which is an interesting distinction from the usual references to angels.

Is this of a similar class to the watchers found in the scroll of Enoch?

Or is this better compared to the role of the watchman of Ezekiel 3:17 in a different context?

What is the "Holy watcher"?